# docker fails with "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name"

Tags: iptables, docker

When I try to publish container's ports to the host, docker fails to add iptables rules:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -p 8080:80 nginx
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external 
connectivity on endpoint:

iptables failed:
  iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0
           --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:80 ! -i docker0

 iptables: No chain/target/match by that name. (exit status 1)).
```

What confuses me is that the `DOCKER` chain seems to exist:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

... and also here:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

---

Maybe relevant:`ip a` shows that `docker0` is down:

```
$ ip a
...
74: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:01:52:de:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I tried to stop docker, remove the broken `docker0` device, and restart docker again. Same error:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker.service
sudo ip link del docker0
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

`ip a` still shows that `docker0` is down. Running `sudo docker run --rm -p 8080:80 nginx`
 also runs in the identical error message as above.

---

System information:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.05.0-ce, build f150324782

$ uname -a
Linux amd8-arch 4.16.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 2 21:12:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: Dont you need to do `iptables -L -t nat ` to see the chains there?

Comment: @meuh Updated: I added the output with "-t nat", too.

Answer (score 0):

Docker 18.05.0-ce is the first release, in which adopt the following networking feature,

> Update libnetwork to improve scalabiltiy of bridge network isolation
>   rules. moby/moby#36774

In this feature, the chain **DOCKER-ISOLATION** in iptable filter table is replaced by **DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1** and **DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2**.

See release log [18.05.0-ce](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v18.05.0-ce-rc1).

Comment: so what is the solution?